# Infinite class of closed sets whose union is not closed

Tags: general-topology

> Give an example of an infinite class of closed sets whose union is not closed.

Comment: How about 1/n?,

Comment: How about 'n' for naturals n in $(R,d)$?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think probably the most instructive example is considering $\displaystyle A_n=\left[\frac{1}{n},\infty\right)$.

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Comment: Why is it the most instructive example?

Comment: Because $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n$ gives you the open interval $(0,\infty)$,which we know is not closed.

Comment: If you want to get an argument for this, consider the complement of this set, which is $(-\infty,0]$. We cannot find a ball around the point $0$ of radius $\epsilon$ that lies purely in the set $\forall \epsilon>0 \quad (0-\epsilon, 0 + \epsilon) \not \subseteq (-\infty, 0]$. therefore the complement set $(-\infty,0]$ is not open and the original set $[0, \infty)$ cannot be closed.

Another argument is that the only clopen sets in $\mathbb R$ are the trivials subsets $\emptyset, \mathbb R$ so if a proper nonempty subset is open, it is not closed.

Answer (score 30):

**Every** subset $S\subset X$ of a Hausdorff space is the union of its singleton subsets, which are closed : $$S=\bigcup_{s\in S} \lbrace s\rbrace $$

Comment: I like this one the most. It's more generic!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Sorry about that, I got confused. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @Kareem Metwaly: No problem, I have deleted my comment too.

Answer (score 12):

The union of intervals of the form $\left[\frac{1}{n} ,1- \frac{1}{n}\right]$ will be one example:
$$
\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{n} ,1- \frac{1}{n}\right] = (0,1)
$$
The behaviour of the interval is already stated above.

Comment: How are these intervals closed?

Comment: This is superbly old, but in the interest of sharing, they're closed because each interval contains its own bounds, and by the definition of a closed set - a set which contains its boundary points - we know the intervals are closed.

Answer (score 9):

Can you express $(0,1)$ as an increasing union of closed sets? Maybe find a pair of sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ with $a_n$ decreasing to $0$ and $b_n$ increasing to $1$? Then you can try taking $[a_n,b_n]$ and see if that works.

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 5):

Here is a good example which clearly shows that the infinite union of closed sets may not be closed. consider the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of all closed sets of the form $( -\infty , \frac n{n+1} ]$ where $n \geq 1$.  Then $\bigcup \mathcal{C} = ( - \infty , 1 )$, which is *open*. So this union of infinitely many closed sets is open.

Answer (score 3):

Rationals. $\mathbb{Q} = \cup_r \{r\}$ is a countable union of closed sets.

Answer (score 2):

As another example, let $X$ be any infinite set, and consider the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) on $X$ (ie all open sets are either the empty set or sets whose complement is finite).  Every proper closed subset of $X$ is finite.  So, fixing an element $x_0\in X$, we have the union closed sets equaling an open set:  $$X\setminus\{x_0\}=\bigcup\limits_{x\not=x_0} \{x\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Example in *R*, take *I=* [0,1] with the usual topology inherited from *R*.
Then the union of all rationals in *I*
Is a union of singletons,  yet it's complement is not open since every ball around an irrational point contains rational points.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sets $[\frac{1}{n}, 2]$. Each of these sets is clearly closed. However, their union over all $\mathbb{N}$ is $(0, 2]$ which is neither open nor closed.

P.S: Note that the union cannot contain 0 because there is no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since singletons in R are closed in usual topology.
We can think about infinite class of singletons {x} where x belongs to (0,1] then there union will be (0,1] which is not closed in R.